# If a ball hits a wall without any acceleration why does it rebound?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Say, if a ball were to hit a wall with uniform velocity $v$, and some force $T$ that is balancing $g$. Right before, it comes in contact with the wall, it will have zero net external force. When it does come in contact, why does it not have zero net external force along the horizontal plane anymore? If it is the wall's Normal reaction force, where does it come from? Since, the ball would not be giving any force on the wall, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball *does* exert a force on the wall. You might also call that a normal force. It is a force, because the particles of the ball try to push away the particles of the wall in order to keep up the speed.

The wall responds with a normal force to withstand the push. This normal force is exerted on the first few particles of the ball that are in contact with the wall. They therefore stop.

The rest of the ball, though, is still in forwards motion. The elastic properties of the ball thus allows for these particles to squeeze closer to the front particles. Soon the ball is fully squeezed/compressed.

Like for a spring, the chemical bonds that hold together the particles of the ball want to revert back to their natural configuration. So the compressed particles push on the neighbour particles to expand again.

The ball cannot expand freely because it is squeezed up against the wall. So this expansion pushes on the wall once again, and the wall thus responds with a normal force to withstand this push once again.

The particles of the ball can thus only move *away* from the wall when they try to expand, and so they do. In this way essentially all particles of the ball are now given a speed in the opposite direction, and so the ball as a whole moves in that opposite direction.

A good way to think of what is happening might be to say that the ball *is pushing itself away from the wall* by causing the wall to exert a normal force. And there *is* acceleration of the particles of the ball during impact from the first moment of contact until the last particle has left the wall again.

Answer (score 1):

The **wall** exerts a force on the **ball** and the **ball** exerts an equal magnitude and opposite direction force on the **wall** - Newton's third law.
That force on the ball causes it to accelerate so that its speed decreases as in moves in the direction of the wall, being compressed (as well as the wall being compressed a little), until its speed becomes zero.
The speed of the ball then increases as it starts moving in the opposite direction - the ball has rebounded.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of momentum.

As the ball is having momentum:

$p_1=mv$

And the wall momentum is zero before the impact and after it; the momentum of the ball will have -ve sign:

$p_2=-p_1$

Comment: Which momentum is conserved? Certainly, not the ball's momentum: it changes sign; also not the total momentum of the wall+ball system: assuming that the wall is at rest before and after, the total momentum is the same as the momentum of the ball, so it also changes sign. Things are a bit more complicated than you seem to think.

Comment: At least in term of magnitude momentum is conserved!